Is there a way to merge these two snsplots into one?
I am not an expert in seaborn. I have created these two catplots and I want to know if there is a way to merge them in one.  
An easy way would be to create a new column in my data for (model+method) and then have 8 different lines in each plot. but that's not what I want. I want for each item in the legendary to have two lines in the plot, one solid and one dotted. I hope this is possible.

Welcome to StackOverflow.  You might want to have a look at the help page, especially about not posting code as text, and about providing minimal reproducible data.
